# Multiple Counts in SQL Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000, group-by

Give the following simple table structure:

> ```
> Departments
> PK - DeptID    DeptName
> --------------------------
> 1              Department 1
> 2              Department 2
> 3              Department 3
> 4              Department 4
>
> Groups
> PK - GroupdID    DeptID
> --------------------------
> 1                1
> 2                1
> 3                3 
> 4                4
> 5                2
> 6                3
> 7                1
> 8                3
>
> Inventory
> PK - ItemID    GroupID
> --------------------------
> 1              2
> 2              3
> 3              8
> 4              1
> 5              4
> 6              5
> 7              1
> 8              2
> 9              2
> 10             3
> 11             7
> ```

Is there a way without using subqueries (which is easy) where I could get a listing of the departments, the count of the groups in each department, and the count of the inventory in each department?

Example Output:

```
DeptID    DeptName          GroupCount      ItemCount
-----------------------------------------------------
1         Department 1      3               6
2         Department 2      1               1
3         Department 1      3               3
4         Department 4      1               1
```

My gut is telling me it's just a simple matter of getting the GROUP BY statements correct, but so far I'm drawing a blank. If it does require the use of subqueries, this isn't a problem. I just wanted to confirm for future reference.

**NOTE**: Using SQL Server 2000 for this particular problem

Comment: @Lieven: thanks for that tag edit. I'm so used to working in 2005 that the tagging has become instinct.

Comment: @TheTXI: don't mention it. BTW, I believe the groupcount and itemcount of Department 2 should be 1?!

Comment: Why group count is 0 for department 2?

Comment: I really wouldn't be surprised if I completely botched up my counts. This is using completely random data so I was trying to add things up. If someone spots an error in the arithmetic, feel free to edit it out.

Comment: I get the same group totals as @TheTXI with my derived table method and using @Quassnoi query. Department 2 has 1 group, so @Quassnoi, you must have your data wrong, your query gives proper values, see my answer and grab my tables and inserts and retry...

Comment: @mike: The initial resultset in the post was wrong, you can see it in history. My post refers to that old resultset which is corrected by now.

Comment: Yeah, Quassnoi is right. I flubbed earlier and had to go and edit the original post to get the correct counts in there. Hadn't had my RDA of caffeine at the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT  d.deptID,
        COUNT(DISTINCT g.GroupID) AS Groups,
        COUNT(DISTINCT i.ItemID) AS Items
FROM    Departments d
LEFT JOIN 
        Groups g
ON      g.deptID = d.deptID
LEFT JOIN
        Items i
ON      i.GroupID = g.GroupID
GROUP BY
        d.deptID
```

The results produced are:

```
deptID  Groups  Items
-----   ------  -----
1       3       6 
2       1       1
3       3       3
4       1       1
```

This will also produce correct `0`'s for the `Departments` that have no `Groups`, or having only `Groups` without `Items`.

Comment: Very nice.  Next time I'll wait until SQL Express finishes installing before answering.

Comment: Cartesian join is almost impossible here. Most probably it will be a HASH JOIN between Groups and Departments, then a HASH JOIN between the resultset and Items. The resultset will have exactly same number of rows as Departments, provided that GroupID and DeptID are primary keys.

Comment: Yeah, my thinking was messed up on this - I was thinking items were joining to Departments, not groups. Doh.

Comment: great answer, but use COUNT(DISTINCT ISNULL(xxxxx,0)) to eliminate the Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: Using ISNULL will return 1 instead of 0 for Departments that have no Groups

Comment: @Quassnoi, correct you are! forgot about the COUNT( ) around it!

Answer (score 1):

Following is at least one way to get the results.

```
SELECT d.DeptID, d.DeptName, ISNULL(g.Groups, 0), ISNULL(t.TotalItems, 0)
FROM 
  Departments d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT d.DeptID, Groups = COUNT(*)
    FROM Departments d
         INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.DeptID = d.DeptID
    GROUP BY d.DeptID
  ) g ON g.DeptID = d.DeptID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT d.DeptID, TotalItems = COUNT(*)
    FROM Departments d
         INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.DeptID = d.DeptID
         INNER JOIN Inventory i ON i.GroupID = g.GroupID
    GROUP BY d.DeptID
  ) t ON t.DeptID = d.DeptID
```

Comment: On the sample data your query will work, but it will select noting for a department that has no groups.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my try...

```
declare @Depatments table
(
DeptID  int
,DeptName  varchar(15)
)

declare @Groups table
(
GroupID  int
,DeptID  int
)

declare @Inventory table
(
ItemID    int
,GroupID  int
)

INSERT INTO @Depatments VALUES (1,'Department 1')
INSERT INTO @Depatments VALUES (2,'Department 2')
INSERT INTO @Depatments VALUES (3,'Department 3')
INSERT INTO @Depatments VALUES (4,'Department 4')

INSERT INTO @Groups VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO @Groups VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO @Groups VALUES (3,3)
INSERT INTO @Groups VALUES (4,4)
INSERT INTO @Groups VALUES (5,2)
INSERT INTO @Groups VALUES (6,3)
INSERT INTO @Groups VALUES (7,1)
INSERT INTO @Groups VALUES (8,3)

INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (1 ,2)
INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (2 ,3)
INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (3 ,8)
INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (4 ,1)
INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (5 ,4)
INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (6 ,5)
INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (7 ,1)
INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (8 ,2)
INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (9 ,2)
INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (10,3)
INSERT INTO @Inventory VALUES (11,7)


--works with derived tables
SELECT
    d.DeptName,dt_g.CountOf AS GroupCount, dt_i.CountOf AS InventotyCount
    FROM @Depatments  d
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                             COUNT(*) AS CountOf,DeptID
                             FROM @Groups
                             GROUP BY DeptID
                        ) dt_g ON d.DeptID=dt_g.DeptID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                             COUNT(*) AS CountOf,g.DeptID
                             FROM @Groups               g
                                 INNER JOIN @Inventory  i ON g.GroupID=i.GroupID
                             GROUP BY DeptID
                        ) dt_i ON d.DeptID=dt_i.DeptID
```

Comment: Using ISNULL will return 1 instead of 0 for Departments that have no Groups. NULL elimination is intended here.

Comment: I initially tried to do it with SUM(CASE WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END), but it turned out that mere COUNT is simplier, and the warning does not hurt actually :)

Comment: @Quassnoi, correct you are! I forgot about how the COUNT( ) around it would count the 0!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not sitting in front of my SQL Server. Here is a first attempt for you. I might not understand you desired result correctly but maybe you can use this as a starting point?

```
SELECT 
  Department.DeptId,
  Department.DeptName,
  Group.GroupId,
  COUNT (Inventory.GroupId) as TotalItems
FROM
  Department
  INNER JOIN Groups
    On (Department.DeptId = Groups.DeptId)
  INNER JOIN Inventory
    On (Inventory.GroupId = Groups.GroupId)
GROUP BY
  Department.DeptId,
  Department.DeptName
  Group.GroupId,
  Inventory.GroupId
```